# Cat constantly vomiting

Tags: cats, health, diet

I have two cats, approximately the same age, 7 years.

For the last 6 years I gave them the same food, Royal Canin indoor adult cat food (those dry pellets / croquettes).

Recently, over the last month or so, I have one of the two cat vomiting daily, the other one has no such problem.

Before that, that cat would sometimes vomit but it would be fairly rare.

- I tried to give food little by little to avoid him to eat too fast but seems to have no effect.
- I've tried to change the food with those meat bag (similar to can food) and he does not throw up.
- I then changed to another brand of this dry food pellets, and the cat is vomiting again.

Besides that, the cat seems healthy and I did not see any change in behavior.

Any idea what could be the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: the first thing to do is to take your cat to the vet and take some blood samples,this is to see if there is a medical problem.feed your cat wet food only until you get the answers from your vet,this is to keep your cat hydrated and it is important to keep the kidneys going.please update your question after you have had the cat examined by the vet.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend having a vet check him cat out. There could be an obstruction, or something else wrong with his digestive system.

I had a cat a few years ago who also started vomiting, while my other two cats were fine. A visit to the vet revealed that she had intestinal cancer. By that time, it was too late and there was nothing that we could do for her.

Cats are very good at hiding illness, so by the time they start visibly showing symptoms, the condition may already be in advanced stages.

The vet will also be able to advise you on dietary changes which can be made to ease his symptoms. It may be as simple as soaking the pellets in warm water before feeding him.

Comment: Another potential cause of frequent vomiting is kidney disease. So it's important to get the cat to the vet ASAP.